# Is Wedge Antilles related to Captain Antilles?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, names

Is Wedge Antilles (of Rogue Squadron) related to Captain Antilles (of Leia Organa's *Tantive IV*  from Episode 4) in-universe? *(G to C canon)*.

I couldn't find any mention of relation (or its absense) in [Wedge's Wookieepedia page](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wedge_Antilles).

Comment: *"**I** am your father"*

Comment: Related trivia: Dennis Lawson (Wedge) is the Uncle of Ewan McGregor.

Comment: The way I heard it in an interview long ago, the explaination for that name appearing more than once is that "Antilles" is as common a name in the Star Wars universe as "Smith" is in the real-world.

Comment: @ForceFlow - I'd heard that too, but I couldn't find any mention of that when I researched my answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They aren't related. Antilles is simply a common surname, like Smith.

> Two Bails, two different characters. It should be noted that "Antilles" is sort of the Star Wars equivalent of "Jones," and "Smith." There have been numerous characters throughout the films, books, and expanded universe material named Antilles, but almost none of them are directly related. For instance, **Corellian hotshot starfighter pilot Wedge Antilles is not related to Bail Antilles. Nor is he related to C-3PO and R2-D2's former master, Captain Antilles, the Rebel officer whom Vader chokes to death in the opening moments of A New Hope.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Ask the Jedi Council - **"Are Bail Antilles and Bail Organa supposed to be the same character?"**](http://web.archive.org/web/20050304101919/http://starwars.com/community/askjc/steve/askjc20000717.html)</sup></sub>

This is also referenced in information about Wedge:

> Wedge Antilles is from Corellia. For more information on Wedge, please
>   visit the alt.fan.wedge news group. On the Official Site Steve
>   Sansweet explains "it should be noted that 'Antilles' is sort of the
>   Star Wars equivalent of 'Jones', and 'Smith'. There have been numerous
>   characters throughout the films, books and expanded universe material
>   named Antilles, but almost none of them are directly related."
>
> <sub>[galaticempire.net FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20100706065240/http://www.galacticempire.net/swfaq.php#2a)</sub>

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the actual reference rather than the fan-written wookieepedia description. Primary references are almost always preferable

Answer (score 14):

[Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wedge_Antilles) states:

> A Human male Corellian, Wedge Antilles was born in 21 BBY, the son of Jagged Antilles and his wife Zena, who owned a fueling depot in the Gus Treta Inner-System Market Station over the planet Corellia.

Given that [he](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jagged_Antilles) was from Corellia, and a businessman, it seems unlikely that he knew closely the pilot of the Tantative IV. But we can answer better!

> [Raymus Antilles](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Raymus_Antilles) was a male Human and the captain of the Corvette Sundered Heart at the time of the Clone Wars and the Galactic Civil War. He served the Royal Alderaan Civil Fleet under Senator Bail Prestor Organa.
>
> ...
>
> Raymus Antilles was a male Human from the peaceful planet of Alderaan, one of the so-called Core Worlds of the Galactic Republic. He was a member of the prominent House of Antilles and the uncle of Corla Metonae

According to behind the scenes,

> The Antilles name originated with a separate character named Bail Antilles in early drafts, before it became the Chewie character's surname.

and

> George Lucas proposed that Denis Lawson, the actor that played Wedge Antilles in the original trilogy, might make a cameo as Raymus Antilles

However, this doesn't prove anything *in-universe*. It is difficult, probably impossible, to prove they were *not* related. However, given that they were from different planets, and one was actually closely related to royalty, it seems highly unlikely that they were closely related. It is possible they shared a distant ancestor, or were related by marriage, but unless new information comes out, we likely can't answer this question.

Answer (score -4):

I wrote this article about Captain Antilles, not to be confused with the Wedge character.

http://www.moseisleyspaceport.org/who-was-captain-antilles-and-was-he-related-to-wedge/

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Could you give a summary of the relevant parts of the article here, if it answers the question? Link-only answers tend to be discouraged on this site, as they're rendered useless if the link dies.