# Who is Bail Antilles, mentioned at Episode I?

Tags: star-wars

In Episode I, among the names appointed to succeed Valorum as Chancellor, there was (quoting Panaka):

> ... Bail Antilles, from Alderaan...

**Is this name any reference to the Captain Antilles, former owner of C-3PO in Episode IV?**

Another possibility:

The leader of Alderaan was Senator Bail Organa (Leia's adoptive father).

**Is this Bail Antilles another name for Bail Organa?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Bail Antilles](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bail_Antilles/Canon), [Bail Organa](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bail_Organa), and [Captain (Raymus) Antilles](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Raymus_Antilles) are all separate people.

Bail Antilles and Bail Organa are both Senators from Alderaan but are different people. [They are each mentioned in *The Phantom Menace*.](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html)

Captain Raymus Antilles' name has been [confirmed by Leland Chee](https://web.archive.org/web/20100329044945/http://forums.starwars.com/thread.jspa?threadID=222689&start=1185), and since his first name is not Bail then he is not the same person as Bail Antilles.

Captain Raymus Antilles -- [owner of C-3PO and captain of the *Tantive IV*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/C-3PO) -- should not be confused with the Corellian [Wedge Antilles](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wedge_Antilles), who at one time held the rank of Captain. It makes much more sense that C-3PO was owned by the Alderaanian Raymus than the Corellian Wedge since [the *Tantive IV* on which C-3PO was serving is Alderaanian](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tantive_IV/Canon).

Antilles is a common name in the *Star Wars* universe but the aforementioned characters are the ones most likely to be confused with one another. Wookieepedia has a [list of characters named Antilles](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Antilles).

Comment: I've never noticed Bail Organa at Episode I!!

Comment: There's also ["Wedge Antilles" of the Rogue Squdron, NOT related to Raymus Antilles](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40009/is-wedge-antilles-related-to-captain-antilles) :)

Comment: @DVK I didn't forget. I was acquiring sources to explain why Captain Antilles was not Wedge. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @LcSalazar He wasn't in Episode I, he was only mentioned.

Comment: Don't forget to mention Jagged Antilles http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jagged_Antilles

Comment: @Richard I didn't know about him (well, theoretically, I heard about him when I read *Rogue Squadron* eons ago). He wasn't in the military and didn't captain a ship so he wouldn't be confused with Captain Antilles, though.

Comment: "Bail Antilles" in the SW universe is like "John Smith" in our universe. There are bound to be duplicates.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20050304101919/http://starwars.com/community/askjc/steve/askjc20000717.html - Possibly worth adding in a quote from Lucasfilm

Answer (score 4):

A pretty quick Google search finds [his Wookieepedia page](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bail_Antilles).

Bail Antilles is a different person from Bail Organa, although they are related by marriage.

[Captain Wedge Antilles](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wedge_Antilles) is a different character from a different planet.

According to Wookieepedia "Antilles" is a very common name in the Star Wars Universe.